# Increase Count Sequentially

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I have a dataset which tracks when a user reads a website. A user can read a website and at anytime therefore the user will appear multiple time. I want to create a column which tracks the number of times a user reads a specific website. But since it is a time series, the count should be incremental. I have about 28gbs so pandas will not be able to handle the work load, so I have to write it in sql.

Sample data below:

```
Date    ID  WebID
201901  Bob X-001
201902  Bob X-002
201903  Bob X-001
201901  Sue X-001
```

Expected Results:

```
Date    ID  WebID   Count
201901  Bob X-001   1
201902  Bob X-002   1
201903  Bob X-001   2
201901  Sue X-001   1
```

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin because Bob read the website on 201901. So it should increase by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use row_number()

```
select *,row_number() over(partition by id,webid order by date) cnt
from table
order by date,id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below sql query:

```
Select  count(*) "Count" , Date, ID, WebID, from table group by webid, id, date
```